# Javascript - Get innertext from onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a foreach loop in ASP.net

```
 <table id="Employee" class="table  table-responsive  table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="unselectable">
            <th>
                Selecteer folder:
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a onclick="test(this)">@item.FolderName</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

now this result in a table with a few folders, now I want to click on a folder, and send it to a function with the text of `item.Foldername` as parameter.

I.E:
We have 2 folders, FolderA and FolderB, I want it to be able to click on FolderA, then it goes to the javascript function  and adds "FolderA" as a parameter.

```
function test(a) {
    alert(a);
}
```

Something like this.

I don't entirely know how I could give the value of the particular item as a parameter. I've done my research and I came to the conclusion to use (this) on the onclick method, but for some reason it is not working. what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Show the code where you are using `this`. There will be someone who will find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by using textContent or innerHTML

```
function test(a) {
    alert(a.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Oh was it really that simple?! Thanks alot! - Can accept as answer in 10 min, also, can you explain what exactly (this)  does? it's quite vague :3

Comment: Here `this` refer to the element which is triggering the event